# What is Metamodel API used for

Tags: java, metamodel

I understand that metamodel is kind of an abstraction of entity classes, but what exactly it is and how can I profit from that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're used for writing Criteria queries for JPA.

Also, it's used for writing Specifications (if you're using spring data)

```
Specification<Foo> isBar() {
    return (root, query, builder) -> builder.isNotNull(root.get(Foo_.bar));
}
```

Comment: So it is not possible to write Criteria queries without Metamodel objects?

Comment: You can write very simple queries without them, but you'll need them to perform joins.  Hibernate has created a cool utility for generating these for you, so you don't have to write them yourself.  If you are using Maven, simply add the org.hibernate:hibernate-jpamodelgen artifact to your pom